# Unable to enable CORS in spring boot with my Angular app

Tags: angular

I've tried the options suggested, for some reason my Angular client on port 4200 can not make the call to my spring boot app on port 8081. I am unsure if its a CORS issue or if I am missing something with my HttpClient on my front end...

my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './../http.service';
import { Video } from './../video';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-details-upload',
  templateUrl: './video-details-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-details-upload.component.scss']
})
export class VideoDetailsUploadComponent implements OnInit {

 video: Video = new Video(); 

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  saveVideo() {
    return this.httpService.postVideo(this.video);
  }
```

my app.module and my http.service class:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { VideoDetailsUploadComponent } from './video-details-upload/video-details-upload.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    VideoDetailsUploadComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Video } from './video';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  urlVid = 'http://localhost:8081/video';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public postVideo(video: Video) {
    return this.http.post(this.urlVid, video, {responseType: 'text' as 'json'});
  }
}
```

My Video is a simple typescript class that is equivalent to my video POJO to be created by my springboot app...:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="video")
public class Video {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private long duration;
    private String location;
    private String subject;
    private String contentType;
```

...and iv added CORS to my controller, as well as creating a config class(i tried them both...):

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class VideoController {
    
    @Autowired
    VideoRepository videoRepository;
    
    private List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

    @PostMapping("/video")
    public Video saveVideo(@RequestBody Video vid) {
        System.out.println("iv at least MADE IT HERE to the spboot controller....");
```

-> iv ommitted my logic after here because iv not been able to get this far, I dont see why not, also, ill include the config class i abruptly added but to no avail...

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("POST");
    }
}
```

...any assistance very much appreciated, I have spent too long trying to fix this...

Comment: can you share the error ?..

Comment: I am not actually getting an error, as my 2 apps are both running without issue, its that they are not talking to each other, so when i try to enter details into my browser/ angular, it gets the data, but it doesnt appear to call the endpoint to process it....

Answer (score 0):

In the main class, add the following config.
The origin is set to `"http://localhost:4200"`, please configure your origin and headers

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept",
            "Authorization", "X-Authorization-Firebase"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: thanks....it stil isnt working.....when you say to configure the origin and headers...i assume you mean in that code block you posted- the setAllowedOrigins arrays etc....because in that the origin is already at port 4200 so that should be ok...and headers-> content-type is the only one

Comment: what is the error shown in the console of angular web?

Comment: there is no error, the app is running fine(as is the spring api), when i hit submit, the angular methods are entered no problem, but it doesnt seem to hit the api endpoint

Comment: Then the CROS working fine. `this.http.post(this.urlVid, video)` send something like this

Comment: ye tried that it didnt work, you do mean minus the 3rd param dont you,.....

Comment: yes, ignore it. Open the *console* first, go to *network* tab. Then press your submit button. you will see the endpoint that you sent. Tell me what is the statue (its a number Eg :200,404,500 etc) you got.

Comment: localhost: 304, all the rest 200 except the websocket whihc is 101

Comment: it should be one status. Check on the api call "http://localhost:8081/video" only

Comment: is this the problem, because there is no api call on the network tab , only ones listed on it are 4200

Comment: It might be. But you need to first open the console then press the submit button, otherwise it won't track

Comment: did you find the api that you requested there?

Comment: just go through this video, you will be able to find https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKpqmXYUWaQ

Comment: no it doesnt show up at all on the console or the network tab....i cant understand why as im console loggng successfully from the postVideo method

Comment: yes, please. I'll try my best to help you in case you don't find out